# Jquery val length not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I am trying to prevent a form from submitting if the length of input text field with the id "num" is less than 10. However it doesn't seem to be working.

```
    $('#num').val().length;
```

See my code [here in fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/PDLdz/4/). Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting your `v` variable when the page is loaded. At this time, the string length is 0. You need to move that code one line down, beneath

```
$("#meetForm").submit(function(e){
// Put it here
```

Otherwise, the `v` variable is never updated, which is why you're always getting 0.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PDLdz/7/).